# Kinect take screenshot with pictures overlayed

Tags: c#, kinect

I am currently using Kinect SDK 1.6 for a project which requires the application to overlay pictures over specific points of the skeleton. I would like to add the function of taking a screenshot of the result, but all the methodes I found are just for taking a screenshot of the Kinect output and not of the extra images added.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) as a possible solution.  You could render all our overlays to the same bitmap target, along with a frame capture from the Kinect's camera.

An example of saving a visual object is given in the above link.